# Data not inserting in firebase database with JS

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to make a login form and i want that info to be save to my firebase database.
I have written the code but the data doesn't get added to my firebase

**Here is the code html code**

```
<input type="password" id="password"  placeholder="Ur password" required
style="background-color: white; border: none; top: 55%; left: 41.5%; position: absolute; width: 15%; height: 3%;">




<button id="register"  style="position: absolute; left: 48%; color: green; top: 60%; border-radius: 2%; border-color: green;" >Continue</button>
```

**Here is the code i used to connect to firebase**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

**and here is the code im using to add the data to firebase:**

```
<script id="main">
        const firebaseConfig = {

            ***The config info is here but i removed it for privacy reasons***

  };


  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var username, password;
  function ready (){
      username = document.getElementById('username').value;
      password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  }


  document.getElementById('register').onclick = function(){
      ready();
      firebase.database().ref('user/'+ username).set({
          user: username,
          pass: password
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the function is being triggered? If your button is in a form then it might trigger the default form submission. Also the `set()` method returns promise so try refactoring the function like this:

```
document.getElementById('register').onclick = async function() {
  // async function                           ^^^^^
  console.log('Register button clicked')
  ready();

  // add await 
  await firebase.database().ref('user/'+ username).set({
    user: username,
    pass: password
  })

  console.log('Date Added To Firebase')
}
```

If the button is in a form as mentioned earlier, try setting the type like this:

```
<button id="register" type="button" ></button>
```

Comment: I tried ur code but still not working, from what i can see the button isnt working at all(and no the button isnt in a form) because there is no alert poping up

Comment: @LirikRexhepi so the  `console.log('Register button clicked')` is not working either ?

Comment: yes that isnt working either

Comment: im getting multiple errors : Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module firebase-app.js:1577
    Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module firebase-auth.js:1
    Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module firebase-database.js:1
    Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined
        <anonymous> file:///C:/Users/TINACOM/Desktop/login/index.html:57